# Ubuntu 22.04 on Virtual Machine becomes extremely laggy after being in use for a certain amount of time

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware, oracle

I am running a virtual machine through Oracle VM VirtualBox. I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 with the ISO guest additions. Initially when booting the machine the first time it is working perfectly, really fast. Then after being in use for a 20-30 minutes it starts to become insanely laggy and choppy, repeating my keyboard inputs. I am running it on a Windows 11 host. I have tried disabling nested paging, paravizualization, 3d acceleration, HyperV settings and much more yet nothing seems to fix the issue.

Specs of the virtual machine:

[image: Specs of the virtual machine]

Comment: "*after being in use for a 20-30 minutes it starts to become insanely laggy and choppy*" suggests the applications you are running take 20-30 minutes to consume all the available memory (RAM), and then begins swapping.

Comment: So what's your host system? How much ram and swap is the system consuming long before, during, and then after the problem occurs? What about the same for the virtual system? Did you adjust swappiness, and if so, what did you set it to?